# RoboGuice setter injection capability

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

Does RoboGuice 3 provide setter injection ?

I don't want to create meesy constructor with many parameters I would rather write some setters for neccessary components and annotate them with `@Inject` annotation.